# ajax for filtering posts by category in wordpress loops

Tags: categories, loop, filters, ajax

I've been looking around for a way to filter my posts on http://www.waziproject.com/wazimagazine/ without reloading the page.

So my question is if anyone can help me out to turn the following into a list of filters that don't require refresh/reload of the page...

I believe the following answer is the closest I can get to a solution: [Using ajax on categories and wordpress loops](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35849/using-ajax-on-categories-and-wordpress-loops)

However, I'm not sure where to implement the code. I'm using the following in my loop.php:

```
<div id="queryMenu">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" id="business_work">Business & Work</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="development_sustainability">Development & Sustainability</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="education">Education</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="health_medecine">Health & Medecine</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="human_rights">Human Rights</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="law_order">Law & Order</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="media_information">Media & Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="nations">Nations</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="political_economy">Political Economy</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="research_innovation">Research & Innovation</a></li>
    <li><a href="#" id="reset">All Posts</a></li>
</ul>
```

Now if I want to apply the coding as mentioned here - [Using ajax on categories and wordpress loops](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35849/using-ajax-on-categories-and-wordpress-loops) - where should I put the different code snippets and is there a lot of tweaking to be done to it?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score -1):

A piece of javascript/jquery:

```
$("#queryMenu ul li a").click(function(){
    var currentCategory = $(this).attr('id');
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: 'ajax-category.php', //sometimes I'm using bloginfo to get current path: url: '<?php bloginfo('template_url'); ?>/ajax.php',
        data: {
            currentCategory: currentCategory
        },
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});
```

Put right path in url. Use `$_REQUEST['currentCategory']` inside ajax-category.php to get category ID...

Comment: Your selector is not efficiently.jquery is trying to find right to left. a - li - ul.....

Comment: this is not the way to do ajax in wordpress