# How do I filter posts by taxomony using AJAX

Tags: custom-taxonomy, taxonomy, ajax

I found [this post](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/35849) that describes how to filter category posts with Ajax and it works great, but I also want to filter my custom taxonomies the same way and I can't get it to work. It shows me all posts instead of just the posts from my taxonomy.

I know the menu needs to be changed to [`get_the_terms`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_terms) instead of `get_the_categories` but I specifically need help with what to change in the jQuery function and the php function at the bottom. I tried adding a `tax_query` calling my taxonomy but it's still not showing the correct posts. Can anyone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: I get a fatal undefined function error when I try to use `get_the_categories()` Are you sure you don't mean `get_the_category`?

Comment: @s_ha_dum That's what the original developer used, but you may be correct. That code is a few years old so maybe the function changed? I'm not even using that to call my category list since I want to be able to list them in a specific order. My category links look like this: <li id="cat-8"><a class="category ajax" onclick="cat_ajax_get('8');" href="#">Category</a></li>

Comment: It sounds like you are doing something different from that post you referenced. Please edit your question to include _your_ code.

Comment: @s_ha_dum Ok, no problem. I didn't think it would be helpful since it's obviously wrong. Basically, I just tried replacing all instances of "cat" with "term." I'm not experienced enough with PHP to know what exactly needs to changed to make it work and I don't anything about jQuery.

Comment: I figured out the problem! Apparently I just needed to rename all the ajax actions since they were already in use for my category filtering. Once I did that and adjusted my tax_query it started working. I have edited it to show the correct code in case this helps anyone.

Comment: You should post your solution as a proper answer and mark it as "Accepted"

Comment: @s_ha_dum Ok, I just did that. It won't let me accept the answer for 23 hours, but I'll come back and do that tomorrow.

Comment: I can upvote you though. Self-solving warms my heart. :)

Answer (score 8):

I figured it out! Here is the code I used:

Add to `functions.php`:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter2', 'prefix_load_term_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter2', 'prefix_load_term_posts' );
function prefix_load_term_posts () {
        $term_id = $_POST[ 'term' ];
            $args = array (
            'term' => $term_id,
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'order' => 'DESC',
                 'tax_query' => array(
                  array(
                      'taxonomy' => 'yourtaxonomyhere',
                      'field'    => 'id',
                      'terms'    => $term_id,
                      'operator' => 'IN'
                      )
                  )
             );

        global $post;
        $myposts = get_posts( $args );
        ob_start (); ?>

        <ul class="list">
        <?php foreach( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
            <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'image', $single = true); ?></a><br />
             <?php the_title(); ?></li>
       <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>

       <?php wp_reset_postdata(); 
       $response = ob_get_contents();
       ob_end_clean();
       echo $response;
       die(1);
}
```

jQuery script:

```
<script>
function term_ajax_get(termID) {
    jQuery("a.ajax").removeClass("current");
    jQuery("a.ajax").addClass("current"); //adds class current to the category menu item being displayed so you can style it with css
    jQuery("#loading-animation").show();
    var ajaxurl = 'http://yourdomain.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php';
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": "load-filter2", term: termID },
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery("#category-post-content").html(response);
            jQuery("#loading-animation").hide();
            return false;
        }
    });
}
</script>
```

I'm not using a function to list the categories, I'm just listing each of them separately. Replace the number with the ID of your term:

```
<ul class="nav">
     <li id="term-166"><a class="yourtermname ajax" onclick="term_ajax_get('166');" href="#">Your Term Name</a></li>
     <li id="term-354"><a class="yourtermname ajax" onclick="term_ajax_get('354');" href="#">Your Term Name</a></li>
</ul>
```

Also, if you want to filter tags instead of terms, replace:

- `'term'` with `'tag__in'`,
- `$term_id` with `$tag_id`
- and change `'taxonomy' => 'yourtaxonomyhere'` to `'taxonomy' => 'post_tag'`.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you use a shortcode to display taxonomy of your choice : 
create a class to declare the shortcode and call this function

```
  public function shortcode($atts)
{
 extract(shortcode_atts( array(
    'data' => 'taxonomy',
    'taxonomy' => 'category',
    //get_terms arguments
    'parent' => 0, //only get top level terms by default
    'exclude'=>'',
    'type'=>'radio' // checkbox,radio
    ), $atts,'astSearchInput' ));

$arrStr =array();
$arrStr[]= "<div class='astSearchInput " . $taxonomy. "' taxonomy='" .$taxonomy. "'>"  ;
if ($type=="checkbox" || $type=="radio")
{
    if ($data=="taxonomy")
        {
        //echo $datatata;
        $arrValues=get_terms($taxonomy, array("parent"=>$parent, "exclude"=>$exclude)); 
        }


     if ($type=="checkbox")$arrStr[]= $this->inputCheckBox($arrValues,$atts);
     if ($type=="radio")$arrStr[]= $this->inputRadio($arrValues,$atts);
}
$arrStr[]= "</div>";
$str=join("\n",$arrStr);
return $str  ;
}




    function inputCheckBox($arrValues,$attr)
{
    $arrStr =array();
    $arrStr[]='<div class="formcb">';
    foreach($arrValues as $k=>$term)
        {
            $title=$term->name; //$term->description 
            //  print_r($term);
            $id="cb" . $term->term_id;
            $arrStr[]='<div class="cb"><input class="astInpuntTerm astcheckBox" type="checkbox" id="' . $id  .'" value="' . $term->term_id . '" ><label for="' . $id . '">' . $title. '</label></div>';
        }
    $arrStr[]='</div>'; 
    $str=join("\n",$arrStr);    
        return $str;
}
```

http://www.webmasterbulletin.net/wordpress-ajax-taxonomy-search-shortcode

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

The code is good, but it needs to small modify to work.

```
            $args = array (
        'term' => $term_id,
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'order' => 'DESC',
             'tax_query' => array(
              array(
                  'taxonomy' => 'yourtaxonomyhere',
                  'field'    => 'id',
                  'terms'    => $term_id,
                  'operator' => 'IN'
                  )
              ),
               'post_type' => 'yourcustomposttype', // <== this was missing
'posts_per_page' => 10,
'order' => 'DESC'
         );
```