# Multiple Ajax Data Action

Tags: filters, ajax

From this [tutorial](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35849/using-ajax-on-categories-and-wordpress-loops), how to create multiple data on ajax action in the code below?

```
<script>
function term_ajax_get(termID) {
    jQuery("a.ajax").removeClass("current");
    jQuery("a.ajax").addClass("current");        
    jQuery("#loading-animation").show();
    var ajaxurl = "<?php echo admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ); ?>";
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: ajaxurl,
        data: {"action": "load-filter", term: termID },
        success: function(response) {
            jQuery("#post-item").html(response);
            jQuery("#loading-animation").hide();
            return true;
        }
    });
}

</script>
```

Thank you.

Comment: Okay, thanks for her suggestions.
I want to ask the script above is:
-> `data: {"action": "load-filter", the term: termID}`,
I want to call the `load-Filter2`. How do I do that?

Comment: @YudiArnanda When writing comments, you have formatting (see "help" on the right --> below the "Add Comment" button for more info. Aside from that: Updates not as comments, but as [edit]s to your question instead please. And: What is "multiple data" in your question? You have to explain yourself better and with more detail. So far I'm unable to tell what you are after.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee The way he refers to the `admin-ajax.php` file is absolutely correct. `admin_url()` is filterable and will stay inline with changes to the file system naming.