# Deploy Subcategories with Ajax not working

Tags: ajax

I am currently working on a project which I am trying to call out the subcategories contents using Ajax. The Subcategories name will be listed as a menu, to call out their individual contents.

I found a tutorial here [link](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/35849/using-ajax-on-categories-and-wordpress-loops), and start following the steps with a small tweaks. Unfortunately, I didn't get the function to work. There isn't any contents coming out after click on the subcategories name. And I received an error message saying "ReferenceError: cat_ajax_get is not defined".

And this error, I believe is referring the the below, which fall on "Code in the index.php".

```
<li id="cat-<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"><a class="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?> ajax" onclick="cat_ajax_get('<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>');" href="#"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
```

Below is the codes I have been using within my wordpress theme.

Code in the index.php -

```
<nav class="category-group">
    <?php
        $categories = get_categories(array('child_of' => 5));
    ?>
    <ul class="filter">
        <?php foreach($categories as $cat) { ?>
            <li id="cat-<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>"><a class="<?php echo $cat->slug; ?> ajax" onclick="cat_ajax_get('<?php echo $cat->term_id; ?>');" href="#"><?php echo $cat->name; ?></a></li>
        <?php } ?>
    </ul>
</nav>

<div id="category-post-content"></div>
```

Code in the JS -

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 function cat_ajax_get(catID) {
  $(".filter a.ajax").removeClass("selected");
  $(".filter a.ajax").addClass("selected");
  var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>';
  $.ajax({
     type: 'POST',
     url: ajaxurl,
     data: {"action": "load-filter", cat: catID },
     success: function(response) {
         $("#category-post-content").html(response);
         return false;
   }
  });
 }
});
```

Code in functions.php -

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_load-filter', 'prefix_load_cat_posts' );
function prefix_load_cat_posts () {
 $cat_id = $_POST[ 'cat' ];
 $args = array (
  'cat' => $cat_id,
  'posts_per_page' => 10
 );

 $posts = get_posts( $args );
 global $post;

 ob_start ();

 foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
 setup_postdata( $post ); ?>

 <div id="post-<?php echo $post->ID; ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
  <div class="article">
    <div class="article__thumbnail"><?php the_post_thumbnail();?></div>
        <div class="article__content">
            <div class="article__header"><?php the_title(); ?></div>
            <div class="article__brief"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <?php } wp_reset_postdata();

  $response = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();

  echo $response;
  die(1);
 }
```

Personally, I suspect something must be wrong with the function code. Since I am calling the subcategories contents, should <'cat' = $cat_id> be something else? And in the JS code, there isn't any <'click'> command. If that's the case, how do the "class" be added in?

Can someone show me some guide or clue to make the miracle happen?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you update your post to include some common debugging tests? Such as if errors are in your browsers JS console, verification that your jQuery selectors select the correct item, proof your AJAX call completed ( try `console.log()` ), verification no PHP warnings or errors are in your PHP error log, verification `$response` has the output buffers contents, etc

Comment: Also, you mentioned PHP in your `index.php`, this is not how AJAX in WordPress works, and implies you're running a standalone PHP file which is both a security risk and requires bootstrapping WP ( and is also incompatible with the admin-ajax.php method )

Comment: My apologise, I afraid I can't answer your questions, Tom. I am just a novice. If you say the way how I use the AJAX is incorrect, do you think you can show me the right way? And I also don't know how to do the console.log(). Perhaps if you can show me the way, I can then send you back the result?

Comment: The javascript `console.log("Hello world");` will print "Hello world" in the browsers javascript console. Open your browser dev tools and go to the console tab to see, any errors or failures will be listed there too. It's like putting `echo` statements in PHP to verify that code was reached etc. Also look into PHP error logging, it's a super useful and critical part of development but where your log is will depend on your host and server

Comment: Hi Tom, the only error I saw is "ReferenceError: cat_ajax_get is not defined". And this link fall on line <a> tag. which I am going to highlight it above.

Comment: ooh I see, you should register your on click event using jQuery, not `onclick=` inline javascript like that is bad practice

Comment: Error Message no longer there. However, Ajax still din get any result. :(

Comment: And you've verified that your PHP error log has no warnings or errors? That the AJAX js code actually runs and is fired? That your jQuery selector actually works? There are a lot of individual parts here that need testing rather than assuming they work. E.g. if you change your PHP so it just returns "hello world" do you get hello world back? What if you remove the output buffers? ( I'm not sure why you're using output buffers, I'd remove them )

Comment: Hi Tom, as I mentioned, I am a novice developer, a lot of times, I am only passing the codes from google research. Anyway, really appreciate your answer, ccprog seem solved my problem. Just some minor tweak, I think it will be done. Thank you.

Comment: You can put your jquery line into the js console to see the output, and you can print out messages in functions, which verifies that those functions actually run, much in the same way you might put `echo "yay it works"` in a PHP file to test something is actually running. I **strongly** recommend you research PHP error logging, novice or not it will make debugging an order of magnitude easier and save you potentially months of wasted time every year

Comment: Noted with thanks. No doubly, I will eventually pick up the php scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
onclick="cat_ajax_get(...)"
```

looks for a function in the global Javascript scope. This line:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
```

hides everything from the global scope. So, this won't work.

You will have to use a completely different technique here. Do not set the `onclick` attribute. Instead attach the handler from inside your Javascript code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    var links = $(".filter a.ajax");
    var ajaxurl = '<?php echo admin_url( "admin-ajax.php" ); ?>';

    function cat_ajax_get (event) {
        var catIDText = $(event.target).parent().prop('id');
        var catID = catIDText.substring(4);

        links.removeClass("selected"); // remove class from all lines
        $(event.target).addClass("selected"); // only add it back on the selected

        $.ajax({
             type: 'POST',
             url: ajaxurl,
             data: {"action": "load-filter", cat: catID },
             success: function(response) {
                 $("#category-post-content").html(response);
                 return false;
            }
        });
    }
    links.click(cat_ajax_get);
});
```

Comment: Hi ccprog, May I know how does these 2 lines work?
`var catIDText = $(event.target).parent().prop('id');`
`var catID = catIDText.substring(4);`
After I applied the command to another parent category, the previous contents brought forwarded...

Comment: `$(event.target)` is the `<a>` element clicked on as a jQuery object, `.parent()` selects the enclosing `<li>` element, `.prop('id')` returns its id attribute, i. e. `cat-xxxx`. `.substring(4)` strips the `cat-` prefix, and you should end up with your term id.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. May I know is there a way I can reset the call, whenever I click on another parent category? At the moment, the previous subcategory content is showing in another category, when I click on another parent category.

Comment: Let's be clear on terminology here. You have a menu with categories, and inside these categories there are subcategories? So, your code starting with `<nav class="category-group">` is one of multiple entries?

Comment: ok, every subcategories will have their own `<nav class="category-group">` within the tab section. e.g: inside Tab A, I will have A1, A2, A3. Then Inside Tab B, Same thing happen. It will have B1, B2, B3. And they share the same `class`, and the same Ajax content holder `<div id="category-post-content"></div>`, but I have changed the `ID` to `class`. Hope my explanation good enough for you to understand.

Comment: Scratch that last comment. I think I have understood it. Instead, I have completed the JS code so we are on the same page. I have additionally altered the class removing and setting. I hope there is some visual difference comming with that. Can you see, after selecting a subcategory, that that line is selected (the class `selected` is set exclusively there?

Comment: The new code is brilliant. However, the problem still isn't solve yet. The subcategories contents still sitting there, after I click on next tab. I did a screenshot, hope this give you a better idea (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/603799/sample.jpg)

Comment: The links selected by `$(".filter a.ajax")`, are these ["Solution Updates", "APJ Customer Updates", ...] or ["ASEAN", "GCH", ...]?

Comment: `$(".filter a.ajax")` is for the latter. ["ASEAN", "GCH", etc.... ]

Comment: As long as clicking on these subcategories leads to the correct selection of posts, I consider your question as answered.